# Regular expression that reads first word and advance to next line

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression that loops through a text and:

- Reads first string/word (string format: 1word/anotherword) of each line
  until space, comma or tab;
- Omits first character of this word if it
  is a digit;
- Advances to next lines and applies the previous two rules;

Example data:

> 1SMITH/JOHN Y     01B  ABC  CBA    BOARD   1    18   123456 |
>   1HILL/ANETH        Y     24D  ABC  CBA    BOARD   1    18   654321 |

I've so far managed to create separate expressions that:

- splits the text by line breaks;
- reads the first word

however I would like it to have it in a single expression.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Post your attempts and flag for which language you will use the regex

Comment: Which language are you using ? `^\d?(.+?)[ ,\t].*$` This with `g` and `m` flags should do. See the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/oR3aA4/1). (Will turn this in answer if your engine is PCRE compatible)

Comment: @Tensibai, here's using Qt (per the `qregularexpression` tag) and it is PCRE-compatible

Comment: @avnr Thanks I didn't notice the tag. But in fact it's not exactly PCRE from a quick read of [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html) The gm flags have to be emulated with a loop. At home now I can't write a proper answer. Maybe tomorow if I've time to dig around Qt syntax.

Comment: The regex flavor appears to be `.NET`.  Newcomers tend to use [tag:qregularexpression] and [tag:nsregularexpression] inappropriately because they can't find anything else with the whole phrase "regular expression" in it.  I'm fixing the tags now.

Answer (score 0):

Giving it a try in QT, derived from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#capturing-text) and untested.

```
QRegExp rx("^\d?(.+?)[ ,\t].*$");
QString str = "1SMITH/JOHN Y 01B ABC CBA BOARD 1 18 123456 |\n1HILL/ANETH Y 24D ABC CBA BOARD 1 18 654321 |";
QStringList list;
int pos = 0;

while ((pos = rx.indexIn(str, pos)) != -1) {
    list << rx.cap(1);
    pos += rx.matchedLength();
}
// list: ["SMITH/JOHN", "HILL/ANETH"]
```

For the regex the demo is [here](https://regex101.com/r/oR3aA4/1).
What it does is:

- `^\d?` Match O or 1 numeric char at start of line
- `(.+?)[ \t,]` Capture any text untill the first space, tab or comma found
- `.*$` Match the remaining text untill end of line.

Comment: Thanks for the example!
I'm using Regular Expression action of Nintex Workflow to extraxt the strings out of these paragraphs, therefore I'm not aware of the version/language this framework uses.
However, I tried you example - selected Split option and applied the pattern that you provided, but it returned exactly the same string as I input.
Most probably the language used by Nintex does not support certain commands or syntax.

Comment: @user3090296: Whether it's programming language or a tool you're using, all we need is its name, and maybe the version number.  A quick scan of the docs tells me Nintex Workflow uses [tag:.NET] regexes.

Comment: Thanks @AlanMoore I didn't noticed the previous comment. I'll try to update within the day